# How to stop while loop from reading each line of a file if condition becomes true?

Tags: java, loops

I have this particular code somewhere in my program.

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    contents = scanner.nextLine();
    if((contents.contains(username))&&(contents.contains(password))){
        call.fileManager();
    }

    if((!contents.contains(username))&&(!contents.contains(password))){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid username/password! Check your spelling/capitalization.", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        call.loginFrame();  
    }
}
```

I'd like the loop to quit once the condition is satisfied. For example, if a specific content is found in the file, it would go to the first if, then call the file manager and exit. If the content is not found, it will go to the second if statement instead.

UPDATE:
It seems like I have forgotten break. I'm sorry for this stupid question :)

UPDATE:
No, break did not solve my problem. Something more of that did. I used counter to read each line and a counter to decrement and increment. After that I subtracted the counter decremented/incremented from the counter which reads the line. Of course if nothing was read, it would return a 0.

Comment: `break` will end the loop, `continue` will skip to the next iteration.

Comment: I'm sorry, as I've wanted to describe my problem clearly, I did it like that.

Comment: @Robadob thanks. I've thought of that but I forgot to apply it. I know it's so stupid of me so thanks for telling :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break` like below

```
 while (obj != null) {
    if (obj == null) {
            break;
        }

}
```

For your code it would be something like this

```
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    contents = scanner.nextLine();

    if ((contents.contains(username)) && (contents.contains(password))) {
        call.fileManager();
        break;
    }

    if ((!contents.contains(username)) && (!contents.contains(password))) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid username/password! Check your spelling/capitalization.", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        call.loginFrame();
        break;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Can you guide me how I should implement that?

Comment: At What is condition you want to exit from loop?

Comment: once one of the if statements is satisfied.

Comment: Lol I feel so stupid. That was such a simple solution. Thanks

Comment: There is a problem with this though. The other lines of the file are not read.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85420/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-friency-loriaga-fernandez).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` to terminate the `while` loop. Also, at a given point, only one of the condition will be satisfied. So use `if...else` construction for better performance (though, the difference won't be clearly visible in this case!).
But it definitely reduces the work of the compiler internally.

```
while(scanner.hasNext())
{
    contents = scanner.nextLine();

    if((contents.contains(username))&&(contents.contains(password)))
    {
        call.fileManager();
        break;
    }

    else 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid username/password! Check your spelling/capitalization.", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        call.loginFrame();  
        break;
    }
}
```